# Google Tag Manager no seeing data in GA4 using CustomHTML

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

UPDATE:
Found a great resource.  So if you are doing code below is the correct way to do it.
What I needed to do was create a tag that "passes the data to GA4" and on ANY event I create that would be custom.  This was the one step I missed.  So this video was a GREAT resource for setting up that single tag to capture the data and then seeing it come into GA4.  Hope this helps anyone else.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClSLdoNKZMI

---

I am using a Custom HTML tag in Tag Manager to set up our eCommerce "add_to_cart" events.
I am following the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?sjid=1767631142882987927-NA&client_type=gtag#add_to_cart

Yet, I am not seeing my add to cart data coming in as an event in the GA4 dashboard.
I have verified that Tag Manager is working across the site by using the Preview and I am seeing data come into the data layer using the TagAssistant in Preview mode.
I am also seeing a simple console.log come in so it is sending Javascript through the Tag.

Am I missing something?

Current custom GA4 code is below:

```
<script>
  console.log("general add to cart triggered");
 debugger;
  //------------------
     var productAddToCartItems = [];
   var $variantContainer = $(".product-essential .attributes");
     var $variantItem = $(".product-essential .attributes").find(".QuantityList").find("li");
     var productId, productName, productPrice, productQuantity, productObj, productVariant, productIdPlu;
   var $variantItem = $(".product-essential .attributes").find(".QuantityList").find("li");
     productName = $(".product-name h1").text().trim();
       productId = $(".add-to-cart-button").data("productid");
   $variantItem.each(function(){
  productPrice = parseFloat($(this).find("input[id*='ClientSuppliedPrice_']").val());
  productQuantity = $(this).find(".QtyInput").val();
 productVariant = $(this).find(".AttributeName").text();
    productPlu = $(this).find("input[id*='GalaxyPLU_']").val(); 

if(parseInt(productQuantity) > 0){
   productObj = {
   item_id: productIdPlu,
  item_name: productName,
  affiliation: "DMNS Ticketing Store",
  coupon: "",
  currency: "USD",
  discount: null,
  index: null,
  item_brand: "None",
  item_category: "Product",
  item_category2: "",
  item_category3: "",
  item_category4: "",
  item_category5: "",
  item_list_id: "",
  item_list_name: "",
  item_variant: productVariant,
  location_id: "",
  price: productPrice,
  quantity: productQuantity
  };
  productAddToCartItems.push(productObj);
  }

 });



 // --- new GA4 code --- //
dataLayer.push({ ecommerce: null });  
dataLayer.push({
  event: "add_to_cart",
  ecommerce: {
    items: productAddToCartItems
  }
});

</script>
```

I am seeing data passed into the DataLayer in the preview on the tag. So I don't quite know what or if there is something in the GA4 dashboard I should be looking at to tie the events together?

Comment: are you sending the event to GA while the user clicks on your desired button? What are you tracking? is it a customised dimension? if so, have you created the customised dimension in your analytics account? you said you have a customised tag, have you created the trigger? have you created the variables ? Google-documentation sucks. Follow other tutorials such as @AnalyticsMania on youtube.

Comment: I really like AnalyticsMania. Great resource.  
It is on click of a button that contains a class.  That is the trigger set up in TM.  I am not sure about the customized dimension, something I need to look into.  I don't think it is because it is the 'add_to_cart' from Google.  The variables is something I don't quite understand why I would need it if the code above should push the data to the dataLayer.  I have not found too many tutorials on using a code example vs click set up. The reason I am using code is because our products are tickets, so multiple types in one add to cart.  So an array

Comment: My issue was the variable event to pass to GA4 . Thank you for pointing me in a direction.